# How to use Mockito verify to unit test @Slf4j logging in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermock

I have a requirement to inject the logger as a mock and verify the log method invocation without creating a custom appender. But I'm not able to verify that log method invocation with this approach.

```
@Mock
private Logger logger;

@Test
void testLoggedEvent() {  
    callTestMethod();
    verify(logger).error(anyString());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(logger);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't forget to inject the mocks and to check how many times the method has been called.
It should look like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private YourClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Test
void testLoggedEvent() {  
// Call the method under test
classUnderTest.methodUnderTest();

// Verify that the error method was called once
verify(logger, times(1)).error(anyString());

// Verify that there are no more interactions with the mock logger
verifyNoMoreInteractions(logger);
}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected, can we use [LogRecordListener](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.0/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/logging/LogRecordListener.html) to verify logs?